# Jmeter warning and error Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes

Tags: linux, jmeter, jvm, performance-testing, jvm-arguments

I am using apache JMETER with 32gb ram heap size of

> HEAP:="-Xms1g -Xmx28g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"

And running the script like this-

```
test.jmx  -Jthreads=75000 -Jramp=120 -Jloop=15 -Jconstant_throughput=75000
```

getting error in meter logs-

> Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native
> thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached in
> thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main]. See log file for details.
> [13.374s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create
> failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k,
> detached.

Please suggest how to handle this issue.

---

I tried this-
test.jmx  -Jthreads=50000 -Jramp=120 -Jloop=15 -Jconstant_throughput=50000

same error

cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
253849

Comment: Increase `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` or decrease `-Jthreads`

Comment: When I increase, it says- "/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max" E667: Fsync failed

Comment: `sudo sysctl kernel.pid_max=200000`

Comment: done, this command works, now I will test with threads

Comment: this led to bigger error [12.465s][warning][os,thread] Attempt to protect stack guard pages failed (0x00007f8c95cb6000-0x00007f8c95cba000).
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
# Native memory allocation (mprotect) failed to protect 16384 bytes for memory to guard stack pages
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/app-1/hs_err_pid31377.log
[12.466s][warning][os,thread] Attempt to protect stack guard pages failed (0x00007f8c95bb5000-0x00007f8c95bb9000).

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at [`/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`](https://sysctl-explorer.net/kernel/threadsmax/) file and make sure that you have at least 80000 there
2. Look at [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Limits.conf) file and make sure to set the number of open handles to either something very high like `65535` or to `unlimited`
3. 75000 threads might be way too high for a single machine even with 32 GB of RAM, you might need to consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)
4. You can also try [decreasing stack size](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-configure-stack-sizes) from your current 1024k however do it as the very last resort if above hints are not enough or applicable

Comment: Apart from this change, do you think my request or contacts throughputs or ramp ups are correct.

Comment: What value should be there /etc/security/limits.conf
#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

Comment: threads-max is = 253849

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adjusting memory, we can keep current thread in sleep for sometime so that current threads can finish and release the resources they are using like this -

```
for(int i=1;i<NO_OF_EVENTS;i++) {
            if(i%5000 == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            threads[i] = new Thread(new PublishRunnable(kafkaProducer, producerConfig, i+1));
            threads[i].start();
        }
```

In above code snippet, current thread goes on sleep mode after 5000 thread creation and other threads are being created after 30 seconds